# Automorphism groups of symmetric graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, automorphism-groups

Which groups can occur as automorphism groups of arc-transitive graphs?

Comment: Just to be sure, your mean "symmetric" in the sense of [arc-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph) as on Wikipedia?

Comment: ... or perhaps "both edge- and vertex-transitive" as in MathWorld? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricGraph.html

Comment: I meant arc-transitive.